# Laravel - Check comepare values in to arrays and check if price is higher

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I have some input fields in my blade that looks like this:

```
<input type="text" name="product[0][name]">
<input type="text" name="product[0][price]">
<input type="text" name="product[1][name]">
<input type="text" name="product[1][price]">
```

if I submit the form, I get this back if I dd(Input::get("product)):

```
MY PRODUCT ARRAY 

array:2 [▼
  0 => array:2 [▼
    "name" => "unicorn"
    "price" => 5000
  ]
  1 => array:2 [▼
    "name" => "house"
    "price" => 10000
  ]
]
```

Now I have another array, that looks like this:

```
API PRODUCT ARRAY

array:80 [▼
  0 => array:18 [▼
    "name" => "john doe for sale"
    "price" => 120
    ...
  ]
  1 => array:18 [▼
    "name" => "house"
    "price" => 12000
    ..
  ]
  3 => array:18 [▼
    "name" => "unicorn"
    "price" => 5100
    ...
  ]
  4 => array:18 [▼
    "name" => "blabla"
    "price" => 60000
    ...
  ]
```

And now my problem

I want to check if in "My Product Array" are products with the same name, like in the "API Product Array"

And if this should be the case, then it should be checked if the price of one of the products from the "API Products Array" is higher than that of the "My Products Array".

If this happens, this product should be added to a UserNotificationProducts array.

The code I made looks like this, but haven't worked for me at all.
Here I need some help.

```
foreach ($apiproducts as $key => $product)
{
        if (in_array($product["name"], $myproducts["name"])) 
        {
                if($product["price"] > (the current product of "myproducts")
                      array_push($productnotification, $product["name"]);
        }
}
```

The "My Product Array" have a maximum of three products. The API Products array up to 100.

Thanks!

---

I tried both answers out and calculated the time cost of both solutions.

The answer of Istiaque Ahmed needed 0.15902519226074 ms

The answer of Hamelraj ( I tried exactly what you did before you posted your answer :D ) needed 0.031232833862305 ms

So the answer of hamelraj is the quicker solution. Thanks both of you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$productnotification = [];
foreach ($apiproducts as  $api)
{   
    foreach ($myproduct as  $product)
    {
        if($product['name'] == $api['name'] && $api['price'] > $product['price'])
        array_push($productnotification, $product["name"]);
    }    
}
```

Comment: you found solution or you need any other solution ?

Answer (score 1):

You wrote `if (in_array($product["name"], $myproducts["name"]))`. But `$myproducts` is an array of arrays. So you do not get any name from there. The following code might help:

```
foreach ($apiproducts as $key => $product)
{
    $product_name=$product["name"];

    for($i=0; $i<count($myproducts); $i++){

        if (strcasecmp($product_name,$myproducts[$i]['name']==0) ){

            if($product["price"] > (the current product of "myproducts")
                      array_push($productnotification, $product["name"]);

        }

    }// end of for loop

}
```